# How is this a series in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The below code produces a Pandas series:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path)

s = df.groupby(['Pregnancies', 'Glucose'])['BloodPressure'].sum()
print(s)
```

I know I can make it a dataframe by using reset_index(). But I am confused how the below is a series seeing as a series should be a 1D array?

```
Pregnancies  Glucose
0            57          60
             67          76
             73           0
             74          52
             78          88
             84         146
             86          68
             91         148
             93         220
             94          70
             95         229
```

Comment: it's a series with a two-level index.

Comment: It's a series that has MultiIndex: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

Comment: Well, I feel stupid. Thanks guys for your help!